# How find file in RPM file

Tags: linux, rpm

I was looking for a file with a gpg extension, and when I do grep gpg `*/*`, it looks like it's in the rpm file.  I'm trying to locate it, but I'm not finding it.

I tried `rpm -qpl Directory/filename.rpm`, but it's not listing the gpg file.  It must be in a subdirectory so it's not turning up.

Does anyone know a good way to get it to list the subdirs out in the rpm, so I can find the gpg file?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do? What rpm are you trying to extract? is it a public rpm we can download?

Comment: Do you have access to the srpm?

Comment: I'm not sure what srpm is, but I have my rpm fie.

Comment: When I type srpm at the command line it says no command found srpm

Answer (score 1):

you can list all files in a rpm with:

```
rpm -qlp mypackage.rpm
```

If you need to extract the rpm:

```
rpm2cpio mypackage.rpm | cpio -idv
```

Comment: I did that already (see above).  The file wasn't listed with -qlp because I think it's in a subcir and -qlp was just listing top level files and dirs maybe?

Comment: No, you get all contents of the rpm by running that command. Try and extract the rpm and see if the file is there

Comment: Then I'm surprised doing rpm -qlp Dir/filename.rpm | grep gpg didn't turn up the file.  It should be that extracting the whole rpm shouldn't make the file turn up then, correct?  I'm not sure why grep of the '*/*' turned up the rpm as having gpg in it.

Comment: Grep is too powerful for this task. It descends in the files deeply, matching strings even in bytecode. You probably are matching a file with gpg in it as a string and not a file with gpg extension

Comment: To test what I have suggested in my previous comments try "strings mypackage.rpm | grep gpg".

Comment: When I tried strings Dir/package.rpm | grep gpg, it listed Ilgpg, without a period.  It doesn't seem like the gpg extension wouldn't be after the period.

Comment: I tried doing rpm -qpl package.rpm > junk.log.  I edited junk.log and searched for gpg and nothing was there with gpg.

Comment: You are missing the point. Grep matches the string llgpg and there is no gpg file in that rpm